# C# Get the control at a certain position on a form

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

This is the inverse question to [C# Get a control's position on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478022/c-get-a-controls-position-on-a-form).

Given a Point location within a form, how can I find out which control is visible to the user at that position?

I'm currently using the HelpRequested form event to show a separate help form as shown in [MSDN: MessageBox.Show Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szwxe9we.aspx).

In the MSDN example the events `sender` control is used to determine the help message, but the `sender` is always the form and not the control in my case.

I'd like to use the [HelpEventArgs.MousePos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpeventargs.mousepos%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to get the specific control within the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [Control.GetChildAtPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getchildatpoint.aspx) method on the form.  You may have to do this recursively if you need to go several levels deep.  Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411062/how-to-get-control-under-mouse-cursor) as well.

Comment: Thats a good start, thanks. GetChildAtPoint is "relative to the upper-left corner of the control's client area" while HelpEventArgs.MousePos gives screen coordinates of the mouse pointer. So I'll need to do some conversions to get usable point before I can recursively search for the specific control.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Control.GetChildAtPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23.aspx):

```
var controlAtPoint = theForm.GetChildAtPoint(thePosition);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is at extract of the modified code using both Control.GetChildAtPoint and Control.PointToClient to recursively search for the control with a Tag defined at the point the user clicked at.

```
private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
{
    // Existing example code goes here.

    // Use the sender parameter to identify the context of the Help request.
    // The parameter must be cast to the Control type to get the Tag property.
    Control senderControl = sender as Control;

    //Recursively search below the sender control for the first control with a Tag defined to use as the help message.
    Control controlWithTag = senderControl;
    do
    {
        Point clientPoint = controlWithTag.PointToClient(hlpevent.MousePos);
        controlWithTag = controlWithTag.GetChildAtPoint(clientPoint);

    } while (controlWithTag != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(controlWithTag.Tag as string));

    // Existing example code goes here.    
}
```