# Detecting controls of a winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a circular area cursor which is a circular winform (translucent) hooked to a cursor. On click, I want to get hold of the controls in the region of the parent winform just below the area of the cursor/form. These controls have to be arranged in circular layout on a different form. I am working on C#.NET.

Please tell how to access the controls of a winform and change their positions in context with my application described above? Like what classes, procedures, resources I need?

Answer (score 1):

All controls on the form have Coordinates (X,Y) depicting there position on the form. So you would Need to get a list of Points (Point are Coordinates) Covered by your "Circle Cursor" then check each of those points for Controls. (Then De-dup your list)

See: [C# Get the control at a certain position on a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776299/c-sharp-get-the-control-at-a-certain-position-on-a-form)