# Is there a way to detect if a mouse click happens on a control or on the form?

Tags: c#, wpf

Im working on a battleships program and have been trying to find a way to detect if my mouse click is on the form or on the picturebox using c# wpf.

```
if (click on form)
{
    do this 
}
else
{
    do this
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get control under mouse cursor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411062/how-to-get-control-under-mouse-cursor)

Comment: usually mouseclick events are registered against a form or a control ? how have you registered the event in your application and against what control ?

Comment: @GETah - thats for windows forms.

Comment: Don't all the controls in WPF have various mouse-click events?  Can you register a mouse event on the picturebox control separately from the background form?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the properties of the picturebox you are using and select the events tab there should be an "mouseclick" event.

Comment: Thanks but not quite what I mean I have pictureboxes copying using arrays what i want is different events for if I click on the form and else if it clicks on a any picturebox if

Comment: You can use the event argument's mouse coordinates to determine where it was clicked to determine if it is on your form, or anything else.

Comment: protected void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs click)
        {
            mouseClickX.Text = click.X.ToString();
            mouseClickY.Text = click.Y.ToString();

Comment: this is what i have to tell my location then im trying to get it so if it clicks on a picturebox it prints 1 image(out of an array) and if i click on the form it prints a different one (using array again) 
with the mouse co ords stopping and just reading as the top corner of the picturebox how do i go about telling what is form and what is picturebox if you could show little bit of code about how to do it would be great im new to programming and not quite sure on the arguments i should use.

Comment: If you select the form, or any item on it, under properties you can see their location, and also their size. Using that, you can determine where your picturebox or list is (i have no idea what your layout is like, so i cant really show much code) and use the location and size to determine your if statement that says if(inside this area where picturebox is) do this, if else(inside the arraylist) do this, else display invalid text.

Comment: Thanks sorted it out had had to get the location and size to come out of the origional arrays before i could do it

Comment: You should choose an answer when asking a question so that when you ask one in the future, people will answer them. If not, they wont think that they will give you the credit.