# .NET Windows Forms – determine clicked control

Tags: .net, winforms

I would like to get **reference of *Control* at any part of the form I clicked**: form background, checkbox, text box, label, anything. My forms are in MDI environment, but I think it doesn't matter much. Imagine a simple "inspector window" allowing to oversee some aspects of open MDI forms.

**Currently** I'm getting that reference by reading `Form.ActiveControl` (or only `Form` if `ActiveControl` is null) of active MDI form – but of course, that works only with controls which can hold the focus. Reference to labels or group boxes cannot be obtained this way.

I know that distributing **Click** handler to every control will solve the problem, but it appears to be a bit heavyweight and cumbersome – distribute handlers when form gets focus and remove handlers when focus is lost. **Is there some more elegant solution to get reference of clicked object?**

*I'm using VB.NET but if you wish to include some expression or code snippet, feel free to use C#, too.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411062/how-to-get-control-under-mouse-cursor dupe I think see if this helps.

Comment: @N4TKD  – I'll look at this and come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Form class has a GetChildAtPoint() method that might be what you are looking for...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6zktd23%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)